# python (django) hashlib vs Nodejs crypto

Tags: python, django, node.js, hashlib, passport.js

I'm porting over a Django site to Node.js and I am trying to re implement the Django set password method in Node.  This is the Django code

```
from django.utils.crypto import (
    pbkdf2, get_random_string)

import hashlib

password = 'text1'
algorithm = "pbkdf2_sha256"
iterations = 10000
salt = 'p9Tkr6uqxKtf'
digest = hashlib.sha256
hash = pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, digest=self.digest)
hash = hash.encode('base64').strip()
print "%s$%d$%s$%s" % (self.algorithm, iterations, salt, hash)
```

and here's the Node.js code I have so far:

```
var password = 'text1';
var hashed = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(password, 'utf8').digest();
var salt = 'p9Tkr6uqxKtf';
var algorithm = "pbkdf2_sha256";
var iterations = 10000;
crypto.pbkdf2(hashed, salt, iterations, 32, function(err, encodedPassword) {
    var newPass = new Buffer(encodedPassword).toString('base64');
    console.log(encodedPassword);

    // console.log(Buffer(encodedPassword, 'binary').toString('hex'));
    var finalPass = algorithm +'$'+ iterations +'$'+  salt +'$'+  newPass;
    console.log(finalPass);
});
```

My solution in Node doesn't output the same results as the Python / Django code.  At this point I'm pretty much over my head and any help would be very much appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Node uses HMAC+SHA1, and as far as I can see that can't be changed (whereas with Python you can use `digest.sha1` instead of `digest.sha256`, but I'm not sure if that's acceptable to you).

Comment: Yeah, my current passwords were created with sha256.

Comment: [cryptojs](https://github.com/gwjjeff/cryptojs) supports PBKDF2 with HMAC+SHA256 but it still doesn't yield the same results. I think Django uses its own implementation that isn't quite standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a better solution using [pbkdf2-sha256](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/pbkdf2-sha256):

```
var pbkdf2 = require('pbkdf2-sha256');
var password = 'text1';
var salt = 'p9Tkr6uqxKtf';
var algorithm = "pbkdf2_sha256";
var iterations = 10000;
var hashed = pbkdf2(password, new Buffer(salt), iterations, 32).toString('base64');
var finalPass = algorithm +'$'+ iterations +'$'+  salt +'$'+  hashed;
```

The above code should be sufficient to validate passwords stored in Django using Node.

Answer (score 1):

So my solution to this was to create a python script that takes the salt and users password and returns the hashed password.  I call this script from node and parse the results.  I check if the hashed password starts with: pbkdf2_sha256, then I validate it against what my python script returned, if it validates use my new systems hashing function to reset the password.

Answer (score 1):

Use [pbkdf2-sha256](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/pbkdf2-sha256) instead.  Had the exact same problem you were dealing with (Django -> NodeJS) and that did the trick for me! :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @paldepind for your answer that helped me! However, the pbkdf2-sha256 module is deprecated. And while it is replaced with [pbkdf2](https://github.com/crypto-browserify/pbkdf2), that isn't necessary either; Node provides the built-in crypto module with a [pbkdf2](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2sync_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest) function which works if you give it the correct parameters. Here's the code with the OP's password. I've also verified this code with my own passwords:

```
const crypto = require("crypto");

// Given the following password, using algorithm pbkdf2_sha256:
// pbkdf2_sha256$10000$p9Tkr6uqxKtf$9OTqv/1X3jvhdyWRm1vwQzMYO9cOzth7hYpoFe0qboA=

var password = "text1";
var salt = "p9Tkr6uqxKtf";
var iterations = 10000;

crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, iterations, 32, "sha256", (err, derivedKey) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(derivedKey.toString("base64"));
});
```

You can also use [pbkdf2Sync](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2sync_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest).

Answer (score 0):

Following bababa's answer, my approach was to create a Python script as well using

"from django.contrib.auth import hashers"

The functions hashers.check_password() and hashers.make_password() provide the functionality needed to validate or create passwords against a Django installation.

More documentation on this functions can be found on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/passwords/