# Django pbkdf2_sha256 JS implementation

Tags: javascript, django-authentication, sha256, pbkdf2

I have a database from django and I want to work with it from Node.js. I have a task: authenticate users. Known from database: algorithm pbkdf2_sha256, salt, 10000 iterations and base64-encoded hash. What steps I must to do in JS to encode some password to given base64-hash?

UPD: found the solution in here: [python (django) hashlib vs Nodejs crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395194/python-django-hashlib-vs-nodejs-crypto)  but Django-generated hash and JS-generated hash not match...
Django generate next:

```
pbkdf2_sha256$10000$NmzpPCQiTe2R$U8ipSsOy3Xz7FwWDHdH/dTei8Xh4Q7NGtdzrCacSfvo=
```

JS:

```
pbkdf2_sha256$10000$NmzpPCQiTe2R$w4jCgWjDilrDmcOBd8K+I8OdwpkKwoVQZMKWH3FvYcKoAMKcwqlewobDocOEGMKZfQ==
```

Password: `Simple123`

Comment: Did you try to get the same number of bytes from the PBKDF? Getting 49 bytes in return is a bit strange if you did not specify that number. Also make sure you use the same character-encoding of the password in both functions - the character encoding of PBKDF2 is not specified (although UTF-8 is hinted at).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By using [pbkdf2-sha256](https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/pbkdf2-sha256) (from your own link) I'm able to generate a hash that is identical to the one you have from Django.

```
var pbkdf2 = require('pbkdf2-sha256');
var validatePassword = function (key, string) {
    var parts = string.split('$');
    var iterations = parts[1];
    var salt = parts[2];
    return pbkdf2(key, new Buffer(salt), iterations, 32).toString('base64') === parts[3];
};
var djangoPass = 'pbkdf2_sha256$10000$NmzpPCQiTe2R$U8ipSsOy3Xz7FwWDHdH/dTei8Xh4Q7NGtdzrCacSfvo=';
console.log(validatePassword('Simple123', djangoPass)); // Logs: true
```

The above code should be sufficient to validate passwords stored in Django using Node.

Comment: pbkdf2-sha256 is deprecated.   you should use  pbkdf2 . 
 https://www.npmjs.com/package/pbkdf2

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work on my data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51613990/nodejs-implementation-for-pythons-pbkdf2-sha256-verify#51614662. The only thing I can think about is the 4th parameter 32 you pass for the dkLen. Where did you get it from?

Answer (score 2):

I recently created a project to make this easier. My project is available for node and is called `node-django-hashers`. The code is below:

https://github.com/kalvish21/hashers

A sample usage:

```
var hashers = require('node-django-hashers');

var h = new hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher();
var hash1 = h.encode("password", h.salt());
console.log(h.verify("password", hash1)); // returns true
console.log(h.verify("wrong_password", hash1)); // returns false
```

This is compatible with django password hashing.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar task where I have to authenticate users against Django passwords in Java. After trying unsuccessfully to achieve this goal using the default pbkdf2_sha256 hasher in Django, I ended up changing the method used to hash the Django password to be able to easily replicate the same algorithm in Java.

As described in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/passwords/) you can modify the order in which PASSWORD_HASHERS are defined in settings.py, I put this hasher in first position:

`'django.contrib.auth.hashers.SHA1PasswordHasher'`

In this way the password hash stored in the Django database is something like this:

`sha1$upSZarr0w7CZ$304b22b1a9e7e5387e79f50e691043d3faf83c48`

If you already have some passwords in the database they will be automatically converted by Django at first user login.

You can easily tokenize the hash using $ as separator; the first token is always sha1 (the algorithm used), the second token is the *salt* and the last token is the actual *hash*.

To match a password you can verify that

`304b22b1a9e7e5387e79f50e691043d3faf83c48`

is the SHA1 sum of the *salt* concatenated with the expected password:

`SHA1(upSZarr0w7CZ + password) = 304b22b1a9e7e5387e79f50e691043d3faf83c48`

In our case the security implications of using a weaker algorithm for password hashing was acceptable.

Comment: For a Java way to do Django's pbkdf2_sha256: https://gist.github.com/JustinTArthur/3528cfca7e644547d6ce

Answer (score 0):

pbkdf2-sha256(https://github.com/cryptocoinjs/pbkdf2-sha256) is deprecated. We should use pbkdf2 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/pbkdf2)

```
var pbkdf2 = require("pbkdf2");

const password = "12345678";
const djangoPassword =
  "pbkdf2_sha256$120000$uUjHWJsRsQj4$d9eBwNfRW/AayPOSMjqYyT26Sm6bsC5GCK9ntDxB8jM=";

var validatePassword = function(key, string) {
  var parts = string.split("$");
  var iterations = parts[1];
  var salt = parts[2];
  const hashPassword = pbkdf2
    .pbkdf2Sync(key, Buffer.from(salt), Number(iterations), 32, "sha256")
    .toString("base64");
  return hashPassword === parts[3];
};

console.log(validatePassword(password, djangoPassword)); // it should be print "true"
```