# NodeJS implementation for Python's pbkdf2_sha256.verify

Tags: python, node.js, cryptography, sha256, pbkdf2

I have to translate this Python code to NodeJS:

```
from passlib.hash import pbkdf2_sha256
pbkdf2_sha256.verify('12345678', '$pbkdf2-sha256$2000$8R7jHOOcs7YWImRM6V1LqQ$CIdNv8YlLlCZfeFJihZs7eQxBsauvVfV05v07Ca2Yzg')
>> True
```

The code above is the entire code, i.e. there is no othe parameters/settings (just run `pip install passlib` before you run it to install the `passlib` package).

I am looking for the correct implementation of `validatePassword` function in Node that will pass this positive implementation test:

```
validatePassword('12345678', '$pbkdf2-sha256$2000$8R7jHOOcs7YWImRM6V1LqQ$CIdNv8YlLlCZfeFJihZs7eQxBsauvVfV05v07Ca2Yzg')
>> true
```

Here is the [documentation](http://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.hash.pbkdf2_digest.html#interface) of the passlib.hash.pbkdf2_sha256 with its default parameters' values.

I tried to follow the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544537/django-pbkdf2-sha256-js-implementation) with the data from the Python code above, but that solutions didn't pass the test.

I would appreciate some help with this implementation (preferably using built-in NodeJS `crypto` package).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would work:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
function validatePassword(secret, format) {
    let parts = format.split('$')
    return parts[4] == crypto.pbkdf2Sync(secret, Buffer.from(parts[3].replace(/\./g, '+') + '='.repeat(parts[3].length % 3), 'base64'),
        +parts[2], 32, parts[1].split('-')[1]).toString('base64').replace(/=/g, '').replace(/\+/g, '.')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to get this working with the other answers here, but they did lead me in the right direction.

Here's where I landed:

```js
// eslint-2017
import crypto from 'crypto';
const encode = (password, { algorithm, salt, iterations }) => {
    const hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, salt, iterations, 32, 'sha256');
    return `${algorithm}$${iterations}$${salt}$${hash.toString('base64')}`;
};
const decode = (encoded) => {
    const [algorithm, iterations, salt, hash] = encoded.split('$');
    return {
        algorithm,
        hash,
        iterations: parseInt(iterations, 10),
        salt,
    };
};
const verify = (password, encoded) => {
    const decoded = decode(encoded);
    const encodedPassword = encode(password, decoded);
    return encoded === encodedPassword;
};
// <algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>
const encoded = 'pbkdf2_sha256$120000$bOqAASYKo3vj$BEBZfntlMJJDpgkAb81LGgdzuO35iqpig0CfJPU4TbU=';
const password = '12345678';
console.info(verify(password, encoded));
```

I know this is an old post, but it's one of the top results on Google, so figured I'd help someone out that comes across this in 2020.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `crypto.pbkdf2` native node.js api

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
crypto.pbkdf2('secret', 'salt', 100000, 64, 'sha256', (err, derivedKey) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(derivedKey.toString('hex'));  // '3745e48...08d59ae'
});
```

It is having the following api:

- `password <string>`
- `salt <string>`
- `iterations <number>`
- `keylen <number>`
- `digest <string>`
- `callback <Function>`

  - `err <Error>`
  - `derivedKey <Buffer>`

So you will need to play with the input variables to get the expected result as in python.

#### An alternative approach

I played with input variables, with not much success, and the simplest idea that I got is to make python scripts that validate the passwords and invoking it with `child_process.spawn` in node.js.

Comment: I am aware of crypto package (I even mentioned it in my question). Did you succeed to create a function validatePassword that will return true for validatePassword('12345678', '$pbkdf2-sha256$2000$8R7jHOOcs7YWImRM6V1LqQ$CIdNv8YlLlCZfeFJihZs7eQxBsauvVfV05v07Ca2Yzg') just like Python code does? I couldn't, that's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me based on [node-django-hasher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-django-hashers)(didn't use it because depends on node-gyp)

```js
function validatePassword(plain, hashed) {
  const parts = hashed.split('$');
  const salt = parts[2];
  const iterations = parseInt(parts[1]);
  const keylen = 32;
  const digest = parts[0].split('_')[1];
  const value = parts[3];
  const derivedKey = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(plain, salt, iterations, keylen, digest);
  return value === Buffer.from(derivedKey, 'binary').toString('base64');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it. Because passlib does some transformations on the base64 encoded strings none of the mentioned solutions worked for me. I ended up writing my own node-module wich is tested with passlib 1.7.4 hashes. Thanks @kayluhb for pushing me in the right direction!

Feel free to use it: [node-passlib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-passlib)